# I want to get NULL when the string in my column is not available How can I achieve this using SQL?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

Column

```
aaa-xyz-bbb
xyz-mmm-ooo
aaa-ttt-eee
```

How to achieve this in Oracle sql

Out put

```
xyz

xyz

Null
```

Comment: Sorry but you need to explain the rules. You can get any arbitrary output with `SELECT 'xyz' FROM DUAL`, but that's obviously not what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `instr` function:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'aaa-xyz-bbb' from dual union all
  3     select 'xyz-mmm-ooo' from dual union all
  4     select 'aaa-ttt-eee' from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select col,
  7    case when instr('-' || col || '-', '-xyz-') > 0 then 'xyz'
  8         else 'Null'
  9    end result
 10  from test;

COL         RESULT
----------- ----------
aaa-xyz-bbb xyz
xyz-mmm-ooo xyz
aaa-ttt-eee Null

SQL>
```